# How to run an ear project on WildFly 29 with NetBeans 19?

Tags: netbeans, wildfly, netbeans-plugins

Right-clicking on the ear project will open the "Select deployment sever" window as usual but the WildFly 29 server is not in the Server list.

I manually added `<org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>WildFly</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>` to the nb-configuration.xml file of the ear, ejb and web modules. It didn't make much of a difference. I still cannot run the ear project. Now, in the Run category of the ear project properties, Server is WildFly, but its Java EE Version is listed as Java EE 8 instead of 10; in the EJB module is even worse, it says Java EE 6; but in the Web module it does say Jakarta EE 10 Web.

Comment: Is your EAR JavaEE or JakartaEE ?

Comment: WildFly 29.0.1, Jakarta EE 10, Java SE 17

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that the WildFly plugin has not been properly updated to support Jakarta servers. Previously I was using NetBeans 17 and had to upgrade to 19 because it was able to start the WF 29 server but nothing else after that, as if the server wasn't started (and it was)

Comment: Can you  try Java 11 ?

Comment: Java SE 11 doesn't seem to make any difference. But after modifying the nb-configuration.xml file of the ear project (to add <netbeans.hint.license>), the <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server> is working. Now I can run the project on WildFly 29. I still think there is a problem with the WildFly plugin, but this work-around is enough for me.

Comment: About my previous comment, there is nothing special about the netbeans.hint.license property. I found out that simply adding and deleting a blank line and then saving the nb-configuration.xml file does the trick; it seems that when the file is saved the configuration is changed somewhere else and it can run the ear from there on. Isn't technolgy wonderful?

Comment: very strange indeed

Comment: I just upgraded to NetBeans 20. The problem persists.

Comment: I've just try with current WildFly main branch build on NetBeans 20 and it worked like a charm

Comment: I have also noticed that after deleting the var subdirectory in the nb userdir I have to repeat the bizarre add+remove line in the nb-configuration.xml file and only then can I run the ear again. So any configuration changes made by doing that should be stored somewhere in the var subdirectory. If you think of anything that might help determine the cause, please let me know.

Comment: I uploaded some files to Google Drive:

1. servers: I have 2 Jakarta EE 10 (Glassfish 7.0.6 and WildFly 29), and 2 Java EE 8 (GlassFish 5.1.0 and WildFly 26.1.3)
2. project showcase102 with 5 modules
3. select deployment server window for running showcase102-ear. Note that only the Java EE 8 servers are in the list
4. showcase102-ear nb-configuration-file; nothing special about it

This is the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mFJdU05PH7XlB0r6qNjUjTqM2TkIaL4L?usp=sharing

Comment: I uploaded 3 more files, with images of the ear, ejb and web module properties window. Note that only the web module correctly identifies the server as Jakarta EE 10; The ear and ejb modules say it is Java EE 8 and Java EE 6 respectively. The link is the same (is a link to a folder in Google Drive)

Comment: The same misidentification occurs in the showcase101 project using GlassFish 7.0.6. So the problem is not just with WildFly but with Jakarta.

Comment: Hum I tried with a war, the issue might be in the ear processing.

Comment: I upgraded to WildFly 30 and NetBeans 21. The problem persists. One more thing, instead of modifying the nb-configuration.xml file, opening the ear project properties window, checking the Run section to verify the right WildFly server is still selected and clicking OK, will also allow me to start running the ear on Wildfly 30.